# VBNet is not creating setup with dll

Tags: vb.net

dll which help we converts text into unicode hindi but my problem is that this dll is working properly in my project when making setup then it is not loading in my project . Calling dll function is given below.

```
Declare Function Isfoc2Iscii Lib "ismapi32.dll" (ByVal s1 As String, ByVal s2 As String, ByVal ilen As Integer, ByVal sc As String) As Integer
```

Please tell me actual path of my dll

Answer (score 0):

You should add this .dll file in your Application folder while building Setups.